# can't get null value in mysql 5.6

Tags: mysql

i installed mysql 5.6 with config my.cnf as below:

```
long_query_time=1
slow_query_log=1
slow_query_log_file="/var/log/mysql/log-slow-queries.log"


datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

bind-address    = 0.0.0.0
symbolic-links=0
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=4

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

i got problem when query sample: `school != "ABC"`
=> result response rows that school != null and != 'ABC', don't return rows have value is null.

if i query with sample: `(school != "ABC" or scholl is null)`, it 's ok !!!

plz help me!

Thank You!

Comment: NULL is not equal to anything including other NULL values. so you can't use = or != to test for NULL values. Use IS NULL or IS NOT NULL.

Comment: With what do you need help? You seem to have the solution right there in the question.

Comment: Downvote because of poor formatting and no capital letters, plus unclear problem statement

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the <=> operator to do this.

There you can see the difference between the results

```
SELECT 'hallo' != 'abc', 'hallo' != NULL, 'hallo' <=> 'abc', NULL <=> 'abc' ;
```